# What is the source of Pascal's quotation on staying home peacefully?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint, monasticism, hermits

Pascal wrote in [*Pensées* S168/L136](http://www.penseesdepascal.fr/Divertissement/Divertissement4-moderne.php):

> all of man's unhappiness arises from one thing alone, that he does not know how to remain at rest in a room. A man that has enough to live, if he knew how to remain by himself happily, would not go abroad or lay a siege.
>
> *tout le malheur des hommes vient d’une seule chose, qui est de ne savoir pas demeurer en repos dans une chambre. Un homme qui a assez de bien pour vivre, s’il savait demeurer chez soi avec plaisir, n’en sortirait pas pour aller sur la mer ou au siège d’une place.*
>
> <sup>[Ariew's transl.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7724): "man's unhappiness arises from one thing alone: that he cannot remain quietly in his room.  A man who has enough to live on would not go to sea or lay a siege, if he knew how to enjoy staying at home."</sup>

I read a quotation from a saint (St. Bruno?) along these same lines. What was it?

Comment: Perhaps??:  In the solitude and silence of the wilderness.. for their labour in the contest,
God gives his athletes the reward they desire: a peace that the world does not know and joy in the Holy Spirit.

Comment: @mlchristians Who said that?

Comment: St. Bruno, according to various sources I found on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something out of the Imitation of Christ:

> One hath said, “As oft as I have gone among men, so oft have I returned less a man.” This is what we often experience when we have been long time in conversation. For it is easier to be altogether silent than it is not to exceed in word. It is easier to remain hidden at home than to keep sufficient guard upon thyself out of doors. He, therefore, that seeketh to reach that which is hidden and spiritual, must go with Jesus “apart from the multitude.” **No man safely goeth abroad who loveth not to rest at home.** No man safely talketh but he who loveth to hold his peace. No man safely ruleth but he who loveth to be subject. No man safely commandeth but he who loveth to obey.
>
> [Imitation of Christ - Book 1 Chapter 20](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1653/pg1653-images.html#chap20)

although Thomas à Kempis (or whoever wrote Imitation of Christ), could certainly be quoting someone; although he gives a direct quote only ascribing it to "one hath said" which I'm guessing just means it's a proverb he heard somewhere. But owing to its popularity, translations and his own scholarship, I'd assume Pascal was familiar with the the text.

Comment: This is very good, but years ago (_circa_ 2012) what I remember reading was by a canonized saint.